# I am wondering where my code is going wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

def coinToss():
    number = input("Number of times to flip coin: ")
    recordList = []
    heads = 0       
    tails = 0
for amount in range(number):
    flip = randint(0, 1)
    if: (flip == 0):
            print("Heads")
            recordList.append("Heads")
    else:
            print("Heads")
            recordList.append("Tails")
print(str(recordList))
print(str(recordList.count("Heads")) + str(recordList.count("Tails")))
```

I am wondering what is going wrong here. it says there is a syntax error in the if statement. I am just trying to make a basic coin flip app.

Ill put my error here:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/liamd/Documents/Programming 
    Files/Python/Cointoss.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "syntax-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 10)",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

Comment: typo: change `if: (flip == 0):` to `if flip == 0:`

Comment: How long did you spend trying to figure this out yourself before asking a question here? You should probably look at the line causing the problem a few more times, maybe check the documentation on the correct syntax of if statements.

Comment: See where the error's `message` tells you `invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 10)`? Look at line 10 of the code, like it tells you. Which line is that? What does it look like? Do you see what is wrong with that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code and it came out to this.

```py
import random

def coinToss():
    number = input("Number of times to flip coin: ")
    recordList = []
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for amount in range(int(number)):
        flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if flip == 0:
            print("Heads")
            heads += 1
            recordList.append("Heads")
        else:
            print("Tails")
            tails += 1
            recordList.append("Tails")
    return recordList

list = coinToss()

print("Heads: "+str(list.count("Heads")), "Tails: "+str(list.count("Tails")))
```

There were a lot of errors, and you should look into it before posting it on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Remove ":" after "if", put it only at the end of the line.
So:

```
if (condition):
   do something
else:
   do something else
```